# checkwinsize equivalent in zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, zshrc

I am migrating from bash to zsh and as part of that I am transitioning over my dotfiles. Is there an equivalent to "checkwinsize" in zsh? I couldn't find one after searching, the relevant code in my .bashrc is

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

I tried

```
setopt -s checkwinsize
```

to no avail. It might be the case that this option isn't needed in zsh (my understanding is that this fixes some sort of bash bug with resizing the windows after exiting an editor).

Comment: Zsh updates `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS` automatically so there's no need for such an option. You can easily test it yourself with `echo $LINES $COLUMNS`.

Comment: Also, you can always find the full list of options in `man zshoptions`. There are actually not so many, so you can read through all of them in one sitting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zsh doesn't have that option - at least, there's no mention of it in the [Z Shell Manual (Chapter 16:Options)](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Options).

If you see issues with your terminal after resizing the window I guess `reset` is always an option!